# jQuery Ajax not loading content

Tags: jquery, ajax, dynamic-loading

I'm working with the code written up at [w3schools (this is the link)](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_load) to try to get some Ajax working on my personal webpage.

Unfortunately, for some reason, it's not actually loading anything when I copy and paste this into an actual file. I have fixed the jQuery reference and I've created a file called demo_test.txt. Apart from that I haven't touched the code, but it doesn't work locally.

Has something changed with jQuery Ajax? Am I doing this wrong, or what? I can't figure out why this isn't working the way it does on the web.

Thanks!

Comment: Is file_test.txt available on the same relative path as the page? In other words if your test page is http://example.com/ajax_test.html then does http://example.com/demo_test.txt work?

Comment: @Adam Yes it is, I just double-checked.

Comment: Are you running it using file:// or on a web server like http://?

Comment: @Adam just locally: `file://`. Does it need to be on a server first?

Comment: It does if you are using Google Chrome.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=40787

Comment: @Adam Thanks! That would have been nice to know -- it's working on Firefox, so all's fine for now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19562/discussion-between-adam-and-benjamin-kovach)

Comment: @worthycaesar Rely? Not completely but it IS a great place to start...I still find myself using them for small simple stuff where the rest of the world wide web just spits complicated noise at me.